# How can I convert boolean into 0 and 1 in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I guess I can do something like `case when field then 1 else 0 end`. But is that the only way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select cast(b as integer)
```

or

```
select convert (integer, b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Postgres conversion synthax works here: `boolean_column::integer`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use CAST, but RS gave me an error.  One option I found online (elsewhere) suggested using DECODE.  It worked for me:

```
Select 'Insert into myTABLE values ( myCOLUMN=' + Decode(myCOLUMN, false, 0, true, 1) + '...)'
From myTABLE
```

N.B.:  I was trying to build INSERT statements....